# Are ReactJS Websites WCAG Compliant?

Tags: reactjs, wcag, wcag2.0

If I were to create a website where all HTML content was generated by ReactJS components, will it be WCAG Level AA Compliant?  Ie. will screen readers be able to navigate through content that's been rendered via javascript code?

If the answer is yes, what tools do you use to test for this kind of Level AA compliance?

Comment: You should probably just focus your question on WCAG. React can generate any kind of HTML output so it's not very related.

Comment: @Matt Oh i see, I can shut off this question if it's not relevant.  THe reason I thought it might be an issue is because React generates the html via javascript after the client page has loaded.  I wasn't sure if WCAG disallows this?

Comment: Ah, ok, I read it as React generating server-side, sorry. You might be more interested in accessibility from a generic SPA point of view (not tied to any framework). This also looks useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861246/

Comment: Did you check [Tenon.io](https://tenon.io/)? It uses a headless browser so it can perform the testing that can be automated. Otherwise as long as your application generates HTML you should be able to test with any tool.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically generated web sites can be WCAG compliant.

See [Does compliance to WCAG 2.0 AA prevent the use of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383151/does-compliance-to-wcag-2-0-aa-prevent-the-use-of-javascript)

The WAI provides a list of tools that can perform some checks. For javascript generated web pages, you can use one of the browser plugins in the following page:

[Web Accessibility Evaluation Tools List (browser plugins)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/?q=wcag-20-w3c-web-content-accessibility-guidelines-20&q=browser-plugin)